# show hide element on mouse hover

Tags: jquery, conditional-statements, show-hide

I'm trying to show/hide span tag on mouse hover of another element

```
<li class="requirement" id="requirement_1">
  <h3><a href="#">REQ 2 - QWERTY</a></h3>
  <span class="fr drag" style="display:none;">[drag]</span>
</li>
<li class="requirement" id="requirement_2">
  <h3><a href="#">REQ 2 - AZERTY</a></h3>
  <span class="fr drag" style="display:none;">[drag]</span>
</li>
```

Basically on h3 mouse hover I'd like to show [drag] span but only for the concerned li element. It should only show the closest I guess.
Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried ? What was the problem ? Did you get any error message ? Show us some more code please :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
$('li.requirement').hover(function(){
   $(this).find('span').show();
}, function(){
   $(this).find('span').hide();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yzFAN/1/

Answer (score 1):

You can use the jQuery .hover() function, which takes two functions, one which will enter when mouse enters the desired element, and one which fires when mouse leaves it (basically, a combination of mouseenter and mouseleave events. You can use .toggle() function which hides and displays an element inside those callback functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery show and hide functions.

Answer (score 0):

```
I Think this will work in your case.

  $('.requirement h3').hover(function(){
       $(this).next(".fr .drag").css("display","block");
    }, function(){
       $(this).next(".fr .drag").css("display","none");
    });
```